# Git-Core 1.7.0.4 for Lenny

Tags: git

I need the package git-core 1.7.0.4 but I cant find it. 
I only found 1.7.2.3 and git-core_1.5.6.5-3+lenny3.3.

does anyone know how can i download the exact version that I need?

Answer (score 1):

add backports to /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://backports.debian.org/debian-backports lenny-backports main contrib non-free
```

set up the gpg key

```
gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys AED4B06F473041FA
gpg --armor --export AED4B06F473041FA| apt-key add -
```

update your repo data

```
apt-get update
```

Then you can install git

```
apt-get -t lenny-backports install git
```

Answer (score 0):

At http://snapshot.debian.org/ you can supposedly find "all past and current packages the Debian archive provides."

This seems like the package version you are looking for: http://snapshot.debian.org/package/git/1%3A1.7.0.4-2/

(Note that git-core is here an empty transitional package, where the actual binary package is simply named git.)

Looking at the dependency list it ought to fit on a Lenny system.